# Javascript to Use an Assignment rules on a Case

Tags: javascript

I am trying to setup a button that will allow one to fire assignment rules on a Case without opening the case.  Currently I have a Button Setup that is working that for everything other than the assignmentheader option.  I am not sure where to assign it to accomplish this.  This will make me look like a RockStar so I am hoping that you guys can help me.  Thanks.

The Button is a Detail Page Button with a Behavior of Execute JavaScript OnClick JavaScript... Here is the Code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")}

var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case");
assignObj = new sforce.SObject("AssignmentRuleHeader");
assignObj.useDefaultRule = 'true';
caseObj.Id = '{!Case.Id}';
caseObj.setOptions(assignObj);

caseObj.IsEscalated = 'true';
caseObj.Status = 'Escalated';
var result = sforce.connection.update([caseObj]);

if (result[0].success=='false') {
alert(result[0].errors.message);
} else {
location.reload();
}
```

Thanks again for the help.  I am sure this is easy but I am newer to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first query the assignment rule Id that you want to set

```
var assignObj = sforce.connection.query("select id, name from assignmentrule where active='true' and ruletype='assignmentrule' and name='xyz'");
var ruleid = assignObj.getArray("records")[0].get("id");

sforce.connection.AssignmentRuleHeader = {}
sforce.connection.AssignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId=ruleid ;
```

I have not tried above but i am hoping this is right way to proceed atleast close to solution